# Can we use kafka consumer with Ballerina as a AWS Lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, cloud, integration, ballerina, ballerina-kafka

I am trying out on ballerina and want to know if we can have a ballerina program which is a kafka consumer can be exposed as a AWS Lambda function.

Comment: As per my answer its not possible. Can you bit explain the what exact you case you want to implement? Then we can figure out an alternative way to implement.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda functions needs to be triggered from somewhere (Not working as listeners). In that case you wont be able expose Ballerina Kafka consumer with Amazon AWS.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a Kafka Listener as an AWS lambda, but you can create a non-listener type Kafka consumer as an AWS lambda function.

You can write ballerina function to handle Kafka `SimpleConsumer` object's functions (Current Ballerina-By-Guide for Kafka is treating Kafka consumer as a service listener), and use that function to create AWS lambdas.

WSO2-Kafka connector offers various functionalities to handle Kafka consumer manually. Read the documentation for more info, it is available on [WSO2-Kafka release](https://github.com/wso2-ballerina/module-kafka/releases/tag/v0.980.3).

You can generate AWS lambdas by adding AWS lambda annotation on top of the function.

```
@awslambda:Function
function kafkaConsumerService(awslambda:Context ctx, json inputs) returns json|error {

  kafka:ConsumerConfig consumerConfig = {
    // Consumer configs
  };

  kafka:SimpleConsumer kafkaConsumer = new(consumerConfig);

  // You can implement Kafka consume functionalities here.
  // For an example, you can poll consumer using kafkaConsumer->poll(<duration>);
  var results = kafkaConsumer->poll(1000);

  if (results is error) {
    // Handle error
  } else {
    // Handle records received
  }
}
```

Then you can generate AWS Lambdas by following the Ballerina documentation on AWS Lambdas.

Comment: I tried an echo Lambda function by importing wso2/kafka, but Lambda function was unable to resolve it while testing, it threw an error saying "native function not available wso2/kafka:0.0.0:SimpleConsumer.registerListener". Can you please let me know what I should do here?

Comment: @PrabakaranThodithotSembiyan Seems like you have two Kafka connector versions reside in the same Ballerina distribution. Check inside `<BALLERINA_HOME>/bre/lib/` directory whether you have two or more `wso2-kafka-*.jar` files. Remove them, and re-install `Ballerina-Kafka` connector. (Or simply you can remove only the previous version jars, and keep the most recent one and continue)

Comment: I exposed my ballerina function as Lambda and while calling the lambda function, I got the above-mentioned error.  Also, I have only one version of wso2-kafka-*.jar in bre/lib.

Comment: @PrabakaranThodithotSembiyan You need to put Kafka Connector jars (`wso2-kafka-*.jar`) inside the lambda zip file that's generated, inside a "lib" directory in the root. You need to create this directory inside the zip file. Otherwise the connector functions will not work.

Comment: Hi Thisaru, 

I am facing the below error while I used the code you shared (with my kafka consumer config). "client object declaration not allowed here, declare at the top of a function or at module level" - at "kafka:SimpleConsumer kafkaConsumer = new(consumerConfig);"

Could you please help to resolve this?

Comment: Which version of ballerina are you using ?

Comment: I'm using ballerina-0.990.3 version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192784/discussion-between-thisaru-guruge-and-prabakaran-thodithot-sembiyan).